# Recyclerview Blank In Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have 2 fragments that will show the gridview with recyclerview
if i use acitivity, my code does not get any problem

but if I use fragment, the view I get is always blank

I have 2 fragments that will show the gridview with recyclerview
if i use acitivity, my code does not get any problem

but if I use fragment, the view I get is always blank
is there anyone who can help me?

This my code

GridAdapter.java

```
  package dev.id.sample.grid;      

  public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

      private Context mContext;
      private List<Grid> gridList;

      public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
          public TextView title, count;
          public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

          public MyViewHolder(View view) {
              super(view);
              thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
          }
      }


      public GridAdapter(Context mContext, List<Grid> gridList) {
          this.mContext = mContext;
          this.gridList = gridList;
      }

      @Override
      public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
          View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                  .inflate(R.layout.album_card, parent, false);

          return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
      }

      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
          Grid grid = gridList.get(position);

          // loading grid cover using Glide library
          Glide.with(mContext).load(grid.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);
          holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

              }
          });

      }

      @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
          return gridList.size();
      }
  }
```

fragment.java

```
  public class xxx extends Fragment {

      private RecyclerView recyclerView;
      private GridAdapter adapter;
      private List<Grid> gridList;


      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      }

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                               Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bank, container, false);
          recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
          recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

          gridList = new ArrayList<>();
          adapter = new GridAdapter(getActivity(), gridList);

          RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
          recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
          recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
          recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
          recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

          prepareAlbums();
          // Inflate the layout for this fragment
          return view;
      }

      private void prepareAlbums() {
          int[] covers = new int[]{
                  R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                  R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                  R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                  R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                  R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                  R.mipmap.ic_launcher
          };

          Grid
          a = new Grid("cccc", 13, covers[0]);
          gridList.add(a);

          a = new Grid("cccc", 8, covers[1]);
          gridList.add(a);

          a = new Grid("cccc", 8, covers[2]);
          gridList.add(a);

          a = new Grid("cccc", 8, covers[3]);
          gridList.add(a);

          a = new Grid("cccc", 8, covers[4]);
          gridList.add(a);

          a = new Grid("cccc", 8, covers[5]);
          gridList.add(a);

          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

      /**
       * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
       */
      public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

          private int spanCount;
          private int spacing;
          private boolean includeEdge;

          public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
              this.spanCount = spanCount;
              this.spacing = spacing;
              this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
          }

          @Override
          public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
              int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
              int column = position % spanCount; // item column

              if (includeEdge) {
                  outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                  outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

                  if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                      outRect.top = spacing;
                  }
                  outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
              } else {
                  outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                  outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
                  if (position >= spanCount) {
                      outRect.top = spacing; // item top
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      /**
       * Converting dp to pixel
       */
      private int dpToPx(int dp) {
          Resources r = getResources();
          return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
      }

  }
```

Comment: are you sure that your fragment is showing and you are correctly adding it to the activity? Add a view with a colored background to the fragment and see if it is visible or not.